# Why don't make apache2 point to my custom directory?

Tags: apache-httpd

Linux release version info:

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 6.1.0-9-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc-12 (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.40) #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.27-1 (2023-05-08)
```

`apache2` version info:

```
sudo dpkg -l apache2
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  apache2        2.4.57-2     amd64        Apache HTTP Server
```

The `default.conf` file is as below:

```
cat  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Set file mode as 755 and ownership `www-data`:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 mydoc/mydoc/build/html/*
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data mydoc/mydoc/build/html
```

And copy them all into `/var/www/html`

```
sudo cp -R mydoc/mydoc/build/html/*  /var/www/html
```

Now i can visit all content in `127.0.0.1`,change setting in `default.conf` directly:

```
cat  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot /home/debian/mydoc/mydoc/build/html
 <Directory /home/debian/mydoc/mydoc/build/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart apache2:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Why have no permission to access the resource then?

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.57 (Debian) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80
```

No such thing happen in my debian11+apache2!

Disabling apparmor can solve the issue:

```
sudo systemctl disable apparmor
sudo reboot
```

Is there a better way to solve the issue instead of disabling apparmor?

Comment: Perhaps apache does not have access to one of the directories you did not change, namely down the path `/home/debian/mydoc/mydoc/build/`. Typically, these days, user directories in `/home` are not readable by anyone except the owner.

Comment: What resource? What did you copy? Why are you making stuff owned by www-data? Why did you copy content to /var/www/html when you then changed the document root to /home/debian/mydoc/mydoc/build/html ?

Comment: I want to store all material in `/home/debian/mydoc/mydoc` ,instead of `/var/www/html`.

Comment: Is apache2 running `chroot`ed on `/var/www`? If so, it won't be able to access any other part of the tree (not even with a symlink).

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but note that `cp -R` won't preserve the source's ownership, you need `-P` for that (or set ownership after copying, of course).

Answer (score 0):

To disable the apparmor can solve the issue:

```
sudo systemctl disable apparmor
sudo reboot
```

Is there a better way to solve the issue instead of disabling apparmor?

Comment: Check for the logs in directory `/var/log/apache2/`. If you do not have any file for error logs try adding this line: `ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log` in file `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and to inspect logs use: `sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the DocumentRoot to `/mydoc/mydoc/build/html`
and not `/home/debian/mydoc/mydoc/build/html`.

or you can try `chmod -R 777 /home/debian/mydoc/mydoc/`.